# Why i'm getting Win32Exception when trying to get info from process inside a backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

DoWork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    PopulateApplications();
                    sw.Stop();
                    int msec = 1000 - (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    if (msec < 1) msec = 1;   // Don't consume 100% CPU
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(msec);
                }
            }
        }

The PopulateApplications method:

private void PopulateApplications()
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
            var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(GetProcessInfo(GetProcessIntptr()).ProcessFileName);
            Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
            ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
            ima = (Image)(new Bitmap(ima, new Size(25, 25)));
            String status = GetProcessInfo(GetProcessIntptr()).ProcessResponding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
            }));
        }
```

GetProcessInfo method:

```
public ProcessInfo GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            uint pid = 0;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
            Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);

            return new ProcessInfo
            {
                ProcessFileName = proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString(),
                ProcessName = proc.ProcessName,
                ProcessTitle = proc.MainWindowTitle,
                ProcessResponding = proc.Responding
            };
        }
```

And last ProcessInfo class:

```
public class ProcessInfo
        {
            public string ProcessName { get; set; }
            public string ProcessFileName { get; set; }
            public string ProcessTitle { get; set; }
            public bool ProcessResponding { get; set; }
        }
```

If i'm calling the method PopulateApplications in the DoWork event I will get the exception if I will not call the method it will not throw the exception and i'm using the GetProcessInfo in other places in my program and only when I call it from the DoWork event the PopulateApplications method then it throw the exception.

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=299
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
       at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32 processId)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
       at Automation.Form1.GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd) in d:\C-Sharp\Automation\Automation\Automation\Form1.cs:line 573
       at Automation.Form1.<PopulateApplications>b__1() in d:\C-Sharp\Automation\Automation\Automation\Form1.cs:line 616
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Automation.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\Automation\Automation\Automation\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: _A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process._ try to disable `prefer 32-bit` in your project options.also make sure solution platform is set to AnyCpu. see if it works

Comment: Disabling the prefere 32-bit seems to be working.

Comment: be aware! this works only on 64bit cpu. so if you want to release your application later you have to release for both 32 bit and 64 bit users ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because there is no "legal" way to manage 64bit memory space from 32bit application. (some differences in memory managing model, different pointer size etc.)

You should change your target platform from x32 (or mixed/anycpu) to x64. You can do this in project properties.